# Why do the words "Africa" and "Asia" not appear in the OED?

Tags: dictionaries, toponyms

I was surprised the other day, looking for the etymology of "Africa" (to refute my friend's fantasy that the word means "not cold"), that there is no entry for "Africa" in the OED. "Asia" is missing too, yet "Europe" is there.

Could anyone suggest a reason for this omission?

Comment: [link](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=Africa) / [link](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=ASIA)

Comment: I don't know whether we can answer the question of why these words don't get their own entry. *Africa* **does** appear under *African,* though, and both words have an extensive etymology in OED. Same for *Asia/Asian.*

Comment: Apparently there is [Afric](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/3637) too. (Though I can't read the page myself.)

Comment: For future reference: Often when users mention OED it isn't the actual *Oxford English Dictionary* but an abridged version called "Oxford Languages" which is Google's preferred dictionary. In fact, if I search "definition Africa“ I do not get a dictionary definition of the word but Google presents a list of dictionaries which do contain that entry.

Comment: If you want to look up a proper name, such as a place name, you should use an encyclopedia. Wikipedia is very good for this sort of information. You need to use the right book for what you want to know.

Comment: @StuartF The OP stated that they were _"surprised"_ that Africa was not in the OED, and specifically asked _"Could anyone suggest a reason for this omission?"_. Responding that _"You need to use the right book for what you want to know"_ does nothing to explain _why_ Africa is not in the OED, especially since some dictionaries do have an entry for _"Africa"_.

Comment: @Mari-LouA By "OED" I meant the full-text Oxford English Dictionary on Historical Principles, not some internet-only abridged version.

Answer (score 17):

This policy from the OED would explain it:

> Proper names are not systematically covered by the dictionary, though many are entered because the terms themselves are used in extended or allusive meanings, or because they are in some way culturally significant.

Coincidentally, OED gives Europe as its example too.

[OED](https://www.oed.com/public/oed3guide/guide-to-the-third-edition-of#:%7E:text=Proper%20names%20are%20not%20systematically,in%20some%20way%20culturally%20significant.)

Comment: In other words, Peoria gets an entry so that they can cover "will it play in Peoria?", and Europe is there so they can have an entry describing its use in referring to the EU or the EEC rather than geographical Europe, but they haven't identified a similar metaphorical or metonymic use for Africa that they want to document.

Comment: You incorrectly cherry picked to claim that the OED considers Europe _"culturally significant"_. The OED quote you cited offered three reasons (not one) for including proper names, and for _"Europe"_ the reason for its inclusion is because Europe is frequently used as an allusion to _"The European Union or its predecessors"_. For example, in post Brexit Britain, _"...resuming discussions with Europe..."_ would be generally understood to mean "...resuming discussions with the European Union...". Provide evidence if you believe the OED included the word because it was _"culturally significant"_.

Answer (score 7):

As noted in another answer, OED contains proper nouns only when they carry a meaning other than the thing itself.

For your purposes it suffices that OED contains [African](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/3638) (£) and [Asian](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/11479) (£), both of which entries include the OED lexicographers' thoughts on the etymology.

African:

> As adjective < classical Latin Āfricānus of or connected with Africa
> (especially the Roman province), specifically designating species of
> plants or animals < Āfrica , use as noun (short for terra Āfrica
> African land) of feminine of Āfricus of or connected with Africa,
> specifically designating species of plants or animals ( < **Āfrī ,
> plural (singular Āfer ), the name of an ancient people of North
> Africa, of uncertain origin** + -icus -ic suffix) + -ānus -an suffix.

Asian:

> In ancient Greek, the place name was used for the continent forming
> the eastern part of the known world, as viewed from the Eastern
> Mediterranean (alongside Africa to the south and Europe to the north);
> in classical Latin, it was additionally used for the Roman province of
> Asia in the western part of the Anatolian peninsula and (hence) the
> peninsula itself (Asia Minor). **The origin of the name is uncertain;
> a relationship with Hittite Assuwa , the name of a confederation of
> states in eastern Anatolia, has been suggested (Akkadian aṣū ‘to go
> out’, (of a celestial object) ‘to rise’ is unlikely to be
> etymologically related).**

Comment: Why have you written *(£)*?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I *think* it's to indicate that the links are behind a paywall?

Answer (score 1):

The second question in [the OED's FAQs](https://www.oed.com/page/faqs/Frequently+asked+questions#entries) explains the reason for the omission of *"Africa"*:

> **Why are there no *OED* entries for people, places, or events?**
>
> In common with most British dictionaries, the *OED* has never included
> entries for names, except where the name has acquired an extended or
> allusive sense: *wellington boot*, *Honiton lace*, *Armageddon*. The names
> of fictional characters or beings are only included if there is
> evidence of extended use: *Svengali*, *munchkin*. On the other hand, the
> familiarity of many eponyms has concealed their origin in personal
> names: *boycott*, *mackintosh*.

Answer (score 0):

Not OED, but according to Wiktionary (one of many explanaitons):

"Ancient Greek ἀ- (a-) + φρίκη f (phríkē), meaning "without cold""

Source: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Africa#Etymology